# Instantiating new redis-server (Linux)

Tags: redis

I'm instantiating a new redis-server in my set up (it runs just one currently). One of the steps is to make a copy of `redis-server` in `/etc/init.d/` and configure it for the new instance.

Specifically, I'm changing values for `DAEMON_ARGS`, `NAME`, `DESC` and `PIDFILE` within the script. Here's the code:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/bin/redis-server
DAEMON_ARGS=/etc/redis/redis-2.conf
NAME=redis2-server
DESC=redis2-server

RUNDIR=/var/run/redis
PIDFILE=$RUNDIR/redis2-server.pid
```

My question is: do I need to also change the value of `DAEMON` and `RUNDIR`? Currently they're set to `/usr/bin/redis-server`and `/var/run/redis` respectively. What's the correct way to configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DAEMON` variable is the executable to run, so that should not change.
The `RUNDIR` is the directory where your executable is run, I would recommend changing this to different directory from your first Redis instance.

Comment: Before I'd seen your answer, I actually tried out instantiating the server without making any changes other than ones I've already written in my ques. It seems to be working correctly. What am I missing without changing the `RUNDIR` location? Is this for better maintainability, or is there misconfiguration angle here too?

Comment: Changing the `RUNDIR` is about better maintainability, it's not essential but makes it easier when you have uniformly deployed services.